# jQuery AJAX: unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to check value of an input using AJAX. Everytime user press a key AJAX is sent and then based on the result from server I am adding valid or invalid class to the input.

.js:

```
$("input[name=username]").keyup(function(event) {
    processAJAXCheck(this,"username");
});

$("input[name=username]").change(function(event) {
    processAJAXCheck(this,"username");
});

function processAJAXCheck(element, toCheck) {
    contentOfInput = $(element).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {content: contentOfInput, toCheck: toCheck},
        success: afterAJAXResponse
    });
}

function afterAJAXResponse(data) {
    result = $.parseJSON(data);

    if(result['toCheck'] != undefined) {
        inputSelector = 'input[name='+result['toCheck']+']';
        if(result['result'] == true) {
            $(inputSelector).removeClass('invalid');
            $(inputSelector).addClass('valid');
            formValid = true;
        } else {
            $(inputSelector).removeClass('valid');
            $(inputSelector).addClass('invalid');
            formValid = false;
        }
    }

    result = null;
}
```

PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['toCheck']) && isset($_POST['content']) 
   && $_POST['toCheck'] != "" && $_POST['content'] != "")
{
    require_once 'classes/AAA.php';
    require_once 'classes/Database.php';
    require_once 'etc/settings.php';

    $db = new Database($GLOBALS['db_server'],$GLOBALS['db_name'],$GLOBALS['db_user'],$GLOBALS['db_pass']);
    $aaa = new AAA($db);

    switch($_POST['toCheck'])
    {
        case 'email':
            $output['result'] = $aaa->isUsableEmail($_POST['content']);
            $output['toCheck'] = 'email';
            break;
        case 'username':
            $output['result'] = $aaa->isUsableUsername($_POST['content']);
            $output['toCheck'] = 'username';
            break;
        default:
            $output['result'] = 'error';
            break;
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

The strange thing is that everything works without problems when I press any character key. But when I press "Tab" to switch to another input (which uses the same function but doesn't return any error - also when I press Tab there!) I get following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input b.extend.parseJSON
jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3 afterAJAXResponse
registration.php?school_id=1&department_id=1:189 b.Callbacks.c
jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3 b.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3 k
jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5 b.ajaxTransport.send.r
```

Thank you for your responses in advance.

Comment: Add dataType: "json"

Comment: I don't think it's causing a problem in this code, but you should declare local variables with `var`, e.g. `var contentOfInput = ...`

Comment: @ADASein If he does that, he has to remove the explicit call to `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: Take a look at the response in the Network tab of DevTools/Firebug, make sure it's valid JSON.

Comment: My first reaction would be that the Ajax call is not resulting in any errors but returning no json response. You can check in your browser what data is being posted to the server. I guess that your if statement in your php script is evaluated as false and nothing is returned.

Comment: You can check the response, In success function `afterAJAXResponse(data)` add first line as `console.log(data)` and check browser console.

Comment: @Barmar but he is getting the error because there is not json to parse

Comment: As @Barry said there is nothing coming as response. On empty textbox field tabbing the input value will be empty.  That means in server side `$_POST['content']` will be empty and the parent if block wouldn't get pass the condition `$_POST['content'] != ""`.

Comment: Well, thank you for your advices. Actually, I tried to console.log the data and there is everytime a valid jSON. I will probably try to use the "var" solution. Interesting thing is that also the TAB action checks the content of input successfully but it returns this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your advices!

Finally, adding dataType into $.AJAX() helped! I've added dataType: 'json' into the AJAX call and removed .parseJSON() from the callback and I am no longer experiencing any errors.

Again, thank you so much @ADASein

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't want to call your ajax function when the tab key is pressed. However, you are not checking for that and `keyup` captures your tab click event as well.

You should change:

```
$("input[name=username]").keyup(function(event) {
    processAJAXCheck(this,"username");
});
```

to something like:

```
$("input[name=username]").keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode !== 9) {    // I think it's 9...
    processAJAXCheck(this,"username");
  }
});
```

You could also add enter - `13` - for example.

Comment: I don't mind if I check it on "TAB action" or not because it will be although checked by the .change listener. I just want to prevent from this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can either check on the key code as described by Jeroen (which will save you a call to the server) or return an empty array (json encoded) from your php script when the post checks evaluate to false.

Comment: You're right, I didn't check the php well enough to see that there is nothing at all returned if the first condition is not met. Regardless of using my solution, that always should be done.

Comment: @jeroen In the end, Honza has now enough options/pointers to fix the problem on both client and server side :).